# how to prove $\sum_{z}P(x,z)\times P(z|x) = P(x,z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

This equation is from $$\sum_{z}P(x,z) = P(x) = \frac{P(x,z)}{P(z|x)}$$
But if I write as following:
$$f(z)=P(x,z)\\ \sum_{z}f(z)P(z|x)=E_{z|x}(f(z))=f(z)$$
which is not clearly to me.

Comment: In the last equation you are summing over $z$, so what is the $z$ on the left side?

Comment: You need to review your definitions. $P(x)=\sum_z P(x, z)$ is the marginal density of $X$ and $P(z|x)=P(x,z)/P(x)$. Now *just do some algebra*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the *definition* of $P(z|x)$?